# How to open gnuplot from mobaxterm?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, gnuplot, terminal-emulator

I'm not sure how to open `Gnuplot` from `MobaXterm`. I've been trying many different commands but they all don't work. When I try, I get the same error.

```
-bash: gnuplot: command not found
```

I'm curious if I downloaded `Gnuplot` to the wrong part of the computer or if I'm not getting the command right? I'm trying to write a program in `shell script` that opens `Gnuplot` on it's own and plots data through the `shell script`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

mobaxterm is not a linux server. So you cant install packages into it normally.

you must download plugins if you can find the plugin you are looking for 
check their list here

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html

and it seems gnuplot is not there .

in this case your easiest solution is to download cygwin and add gnuplot on it which is possible

other option is to run small virtual machine so you can test on it

in all cases mobaxterm is not real linux enviroment so to be sure your shel do work on normal linux machines you will need to develop and test on real linux

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into cygwin then.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the winbuild of gnuplot and add the path to the bin directory, with gnuplot.exe in it, to mobaxterm's `PATH` (probably set it in .initrc or .bashrc, whichever you prefer).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand, could you elaborate? I'm very new to all of these programs.

Answer (score 0):

`MobaXterm` is a standalone program which 'emulates' a `Linux` terminal but has no idea about your frame system (e.g. your `Windows` and your programs). So if you type 'gnuplot' Moba has no idea what is this. You have to

change the current directory to where is wgnuplot.exe e.g.:

```
cd /drives/c/Program\ Files/gnuplot-4/bin
./wgnuplot.exe
```

or run directly it:

```
/drives/c/Program\ Files/gnuplot-4/bin/wgnuplot.exe
```

or change your $PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/drives/c/Program\ Files/gnuplot-4/bin
wgnuplot.exe
```

or create a script named 'gnuplot' which runs wgnuplot.exe

```
#File name: 'gnuplot'
#!/bin/sh
/drives/c/Program\ Files/gnuplot-4/bin/wgnuplot.exe
```

and place it into some $PATH directory:

```
`/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/drives/c/WINDOWS` or `/drives/c/WINDOWS/system32`
```

or... :)

Comment: Thank you for all of the explanation. I'd like to run gnuplot directly, but when I input the code I get back an error 

-bash: /drives/c/Program Files/gnuplot/bin/wgnuplot.exe: No such file or directory


Do you have any idea at what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have wgnuplot.exe in 'C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin' ? Did you miss to type '\ ' to make a white space ? (You have to type '/drives/c/Program\ Files/gnuplot/bin/wgnuplot.exe')

Comment: Try to 'list' with `ls /drives`  `ls /drives/c` `ls /drives/c/Program\ Files`... ect

Comment: I've gone through the whole process and have confirmed that wgnuplot.exe is in 'C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin' (I thought maybe it wasn't there at first too). But even when I try to type the command ls /drives Moba returns with the same error 'ls: /dries/c: No such file or directory'.

Comment: Not dires but drives ;-)
Interesting...  what is in the root (`ls /`)? Sometimes there is `/cygdrive`

Comment: Haha sorry, my bad. And I'm not really sure. When I type [ls /] there's a lot of directories(?) listed, and I only really started using moba a few weeks ago so I'm not really sure what these all mean. I'm also working in what my boss described to me as a network with her and other scientists... so basically I'm quite lost and I'm not sure how to access my computer files from their directories. Thank you for all the help so far by the way, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is a lot of directories corresponding to the standard UNIX directory structure where every directory has or had a function. E.g. /bin means "binaries" (like .exe programs in Windows) - this directory designated to contain 'runable programs'. But there are also /usr/local/bin /usr/bin ect... A little complex and historical :)

Comment: Okay, interesting. Well regardless I'm not finding drive or cygdrive anywhere, do I need to maybe download gnuplot to mobaxterm somehow or? At the moment I'm just not seeing any way to access the files on my windows system through mobaxterm

Comment: What is the result of `ls /` ?

Comment: afs, bin, boot, etc, export, home, lib, lib64, media, msrc, opt, proc, sbin,  share, sys, tftpboot, tmp, usr, var.


 I've removed the ones I don't have access to, the non-directories, and the empty directories that were listed.

Comment: Then try `/media/c` or `/mnt/c`! If it still does not work, ask "How to access Windows drive C:\ with Mobaxterm?" at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found out is to use the Moba Package Manager to install the win version of gnuplot.
Open MobaXterm and type MobApt. An GUI will open up and you can type in "gnuplot" in the filter field.
Just select and install the package, MobApt will take care of any dependencies for you.